# Sums of two integer squares in arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Is there an explicit formula in the literature for the number of representations of a positive integer $n$ as a sum of two integer squares, the second of which is divisible by $5$? So this means to count integer representations of $n$ by the quadratic form $x^2+ 5^2 y^2$.

I would hope for something as nice as the formula related to representations as a sum of two integer squares,
$$ \sum_{\substack{ d\in \mathbb{N} \\ d \text{ divides } n}} \chi(d),$$ where $\chi$ is the non-principal character modulo $4$.

In general, I would be interested in the number of representations by any quadratic form of the shape $d_1^2 x^2+ d_2^2 y^2$, where $d_1,d_2$ are non-zero integers.

Comment: Things are not so simple in general. Have a look at the book https://www.amazon.com/Primes-Form-x2-ny2-Multiplication/dp/1118390180

Comment: yes that is a great but how is it useful? the square coefficients make all the quadratic forms in the question equivalent to $x^2+y^2$ so not sure how quadratic fields etc.etc. are relevant.

Comment: I believe that the kind of formula you expect does not exist. Unfortuately, I am no expert here, and I don't have the time to check the literature.